# How to force resize windows screen resolution to match that of the Citrix window

Tags: citrix

When I log into Citrix on two screens, it automatically spans to both. This is annoying as I don't need it that big. So I hit shift-f2 and resize the window, however, the underlying (remote) windows resolution stays the same.

How to force the underlying Windows to adjust to new size of ctrix screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

- Shift+F2 to take session out of full screen mode and turn it into windowed mode.
- Move and resize window such that each and every pixel is on a single screen.
- Click the `Maximize` button of the window.

This triggers resizing of the session to fit the window for me.

Comment: I can confirm this works. Now if I'd knew how to have the windows to resize to an arbitrary Citrix window size... :)